# Regarding Row Selection & Event Triggering in Access

Tags: events, ms-access, triggers

All I have
1 Form
having 1 command button and 1 label

2 Tables
 named father and child

1 Query
that has fields of father and child

changing form to layout mode
I have placed father table and Query in form by directly dragging them into form

What I am doing right now is:
I click the record on father table and click button that has following code:

```
Label10.Caption = Father.Form!ID
Query.Requery
```

So my Query takes the id from label10 and populates the grid accordingly

This is all happening by the command button and All I want to be done is directly without the involment of button

what I want to do is
whenever a user clicks a record in father table, it should trigger an event that populates the Query table against the id of father table
without involment of button.

Anybody can help?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow; when tagging your question please try and use the correct ones, this makes it much more likely to be answered. For instance, [tag:access] has _"DO NOT USE"_ written on it on hover whereas [tag:ms-access] clearly say's it's about ms-access...

Comment: ok sir i will take care for future :)

Comment: Can the child table have 2 records for 1 father record like a record in father would be Ford and two child entries would focus and fusion.